# If (in_array) not making any sense

Tags: php, if-statement

I've got a conundrum of nonsensical logic. I'm using a basic example because I need this exact if statement for an error display in a form, but for some reason this one is coming back true instead of false.

```
<?php
if (in_array('state', $missing)) { print_r($missing);};
?>
```

So, that's my code block, and here's the output.

```
Array ( [0] => firstname 
[1] => lastname 
[2] => phone 
[3] => email 
[4] => password 
[5] => passverify 
[6] => age 
[7] => gender 
[8] => addressfirst 
[9] => city 
[10] => zip 
[11] => distance 
[12] => 1 )
```

It's outputting the $missing array and there is clearly no "state" within the array. The in_array should be returning false and causing the if statement to be bypassed, but it's not and I have no clue why.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's not outputting the $missing in some other location as well? This indeed looks like it should work.

Comment: Try it with `in_array('state', $missing, TRUE)` to use strict comparison Perhaps the `1` is loosely equal to 'state': http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: `state` losely equals `0`

Comment: Adding in that TRUE solved it! Thanks so much =]

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer.

Comment: Can you provide use with a *full* example? Including creating your array? (Or at least a `var_dump` of the array rather than a `print_r`—that will show us the types.) As it stands, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Matt Gibson This all comes from a long form with nearly 600 lines of code thus far, and trying to separate out the specific parts needed to present the whole problem would be very arduous. I used the solution of adding TRUE in and I've tested the form in many situations to see if it catches the error properly. As far as I can tell, it's working perfectly now.